# Fatal Error in Visual Studio 2022 solution

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Since 01/15/2022, I have been getting the following fatal Visual Studio 2022 Error in Visual Studio 2022 for all my projects.

I don't know that I changed anything.
It must be somehow related to an update of either Visual Studio 2022 or TFS Online.
All my Visual Studio Solutions are working fine.
But every time I open Visual Studio 2022 and load my projects, I get a "fatal error message" and Visual Studio 2022 closes all my projects "Unloading Projects" and I have to open the full solution a 2nd time. After the 2nd time open, I get red crosses on the projects. However, the build process works fine.
I have also already resolved yesterday, the .vs directory and all bin and obj directories in the respective projects. After that, it also worked wonderfully again and everything was displayed correctly. However, this morning I reloaded the entire Visual Studio 2022 Solution and the same problem is present again.

```
=====================
16.01.2022 08:43:49
LimitedFunctionality
System.AggregateException: Project system data flow 'OutputGroupsService' closed because of an exception.
Schwerwiegender Fehler (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)) ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Schwerwiegender Fehler (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
   at Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsSolutionWorkingFolders.GetFolder(UInt32 location, Guid guidProject, Boolean fVersionSpecific, Boolean fEnsureCreated, Boolean& pfIsTemporary, String& pszBstrFullPath)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.DesignTimeBuildManagerService.DesignTimeBuildHost.FetchSolutionInfo()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.DesignTimeBuildManagerService.DesignTimeBuildHost.<<-ctor>b__20_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.AsyncLazy`1.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<<GetValueAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Build.DesignTimeBuildManagerService.<BuildUsingDesignTimeBuildServiceAsync>d__52.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.DesignTimeBuildManagerService.DesignTimeBuildHost.<GetSolutionGlobalPropertiesAsync>d__35.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Build.DesignTimeBuildManagerService.<BuildAsync>d__50.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Build.DesignTimeBuildManagerService.<BuildAsync>d__50.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectServices.DesignTimeBuildService.<CreateDesignTimeBuilderAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Build.DesignTimeBuilderService.BuilderLifetimeHelper.<InitializeCoreAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.OnceInitializedOnceDisposedAsync.<<-ctor>b__8_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.AwaitExtensions.ExecuteContinuationSynchronouslyAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.AsyncLazy`1.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<<GetValueAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Build.DesignTimeBuildManagerService.<BuildAsync>d__50.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Build.DesignTimeBuilderService.<BuildAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Build.DesignTimeBuildManagerService.<BuildAsync>d__50.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Build.DesignTimeBuilderService.<BuildAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.ProjectBuildSnapshotService.<>c__DisplayClass73_0.<<UpdateSnapshotCoreAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.CommonProjectSystemTools.<>c__DisplayClass14_0`1.<<LoadedProjectAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.<JoinAsync>d__76.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask`1.<<JoinAsync>g__JoinSlowAsync|3_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.ProjectBuildSnapshotService.<UpdateSnapshotCoreAsync>d__73.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.CustomizableBlockSubscriberBase`3.<UpdateSnapshotAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.CustomizableBlockSubscriberBase`3.<>c__DisplayClass28_0.<<Initialize>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.<JoinAsync>d__76.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.CustomizableBlockSubscriberBase`3.<UpdateSnapshotAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.CustomizableBlockSubscriberBase`3.<>c__DisplayClass28_0.<<Initialize>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.<JoinAsync>d__76.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.CustomizableBlockSubscriberBase`3.<<Initialize>b__28_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.TransformBlockSlim`2.TransformManyBlockSlimAsync.<ProcessInputAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.CustomizableBlockSubscriberBase`3.<>c__DisplayClass28_0.<<Initialize>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.<JoinAsync>d__76.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.CustomizableBlockSubscriberBase`3.<<Initialize>b__28_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.TransformBlockSlim`2.TransformManyBlockSlimAsync.<ProcessInputAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.DataReceivingBlockSlim`1.<ProcessInputQueueAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.DataReceivingBlockSlim`1.<ProcessInputQueueAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8000FFFF): Schwerwiegender Fehler (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
   at Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsSolutionWorkingFolders.GetFolder(UInt32 location, Guid guidProject, Boolean fVersionSpecific, Boolean fEnsureCreated, Boolean& pfIsTemporary, String& pszBstrFullPath)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.DesignTimeBuildManagerService.DesignTimeBuildHost.FetchSolutionInfo()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.DesignTimeBuildManagerService.DesignTimeBuildHost.<<-ctor>b__20_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.AsyncLazy`1.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<<GetValueAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Build.DesignTimeBuildManagerService.<BuildUsingDesignTimeBuildServiceAsync>d__52.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.DesignTimeBuildManagerService.DesignTimeBuildHost.<GetSolutionGlobalPropertiesAsync>d__35.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Build.DesignTimeBuildManagerService.<BuildAsync>d__50.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Build.DesignTimeBuildManagerService.<BuildAsync>d__50.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectServices.DesignTimeBuildService.<CreateDesignTimeBuilderAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Build.DesignTimeBuilderService.BuilderLifetimeHelper.<InitializeCoreAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.OnceInitializedOnceDisposedAsync.<<-ctor>b__8_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.AwaitExtensions.ExecuteContinuationSynchronouslyAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.AsyncLazy`1.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<<GetValueAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Build.DesignTimeBuildManagerService.<BuildAsync>d__50.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Build.DesignTimeBuilderService.<BuildAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Build.DesignTimeBuildManagerService.<BuildAsync>d__50.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Build.DesignTimeBuilderService.<BuildAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.ProjectBuildSnapshotService.<>c__DisplayClass73_0.<<UpdateSnapshotCoreAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.CommonProjectSystemTools.<>c__DisplayClass14_0`1.<<LoadedProjectAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.<JoinAsync>d__76.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask`1.<<JoinAsync>g__JoinSlowAsync|3_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.ProjectBuildSnapshotService.<UpdateSnapshotCoreAsync>d__73.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.CustomizableBlockSubscriberBase`3.<UpdateSnapshotAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.CustomizableBlockSubscriberBase`3.<>c__DisplayClass28_0.<<Initialize>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.<JoinAsync>d__76.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.CustomizableBlockSubscriberBase`3.<UpdateSnapshotAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.CustomizableBlockSubscriberBase`3.<>c__DisplayClass28_0.<<Initialize>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.<JoinAsync>d__76.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.CustomizableBlockSubscriberBase`3.<<Initialize>b__28_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.TransformBlockSlim`2.TransformManyBlockSlimAsync.<ProcessInputAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.CustomizableBlockSubscriberBase`3.<>c__DisplayClass28_0.<<Initialize>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.<JoinAsync>d__76.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.CustomizableBlockSubscriberBase`3.<<Initialize>b__28_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.TransformBlockSlim`2.TransformManyBlockSlimAsync.<ProcessInputAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.DataReceivingBlockSlim`1.<ProcessInputQueueAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.DataReceivingBlockSlim`1.<ProcessInputQueueAsync>d__5.MoveNext()<---
```

Comment: Have you tried repairing visual studio? Have you tried reverting to the last version that was working for you? Have you tried updating to the latest version of visual studio? Are there possibly permission issues on the file system (the exception is about problems accessing a folder)? Have you ran a `chkdsk /f` on your desk to verify there are no issues?

Comment: Have you submitted this as feedback to visual studio using the built-in report feature (which will capture more diagnostic data so the Product Group can analyze the issue).

Comment: What exact version of Visual Studio 2022 are you running?

Comment: I am using: Version 17.1.0 Preview 2.0

Comment: I tried to get a new version via the Visual Studio update channel. But with my current version I seem to be completely up to date.

Comment: I also tried updating/stripping down the nuget packages. Everything did not work. I could not even go from .net 6 down to .net 5. Neither in the settings for the project, nor in nuget.... Which of course is logical. (at least nuget).

Comment: I have now opened the Solution in the latest Visual Studio 2019 version and set everything back to .net 5. Both the individual projects and the nuget packages. This was the only current solution for me. I will uninstall Visual Studio 2022 completely and wait to see what comes after the preview versions.

Comment: At the moment my Solution is fully working again with the current version of Visual Studio 2019. I think Visual Studio 2022 and .net 6 I will wait for a long time. I have had so many problems with Visual Studio 2022 and .net 6 in the last few weeks. I can understand that it was a preview version, but there were just too many bugs that actively prevented me from working. I was just left solving problems. I think I reported over 10 bugs directly to Microsoft.

Comment: Have you tried the non-preview build?

Comment: Yes, I had that one before. From my point of view, it was much worse. That's why I went to the Preview 2 version.

Comment: Please try to verify with a different machine. VS2022 does have a few issues, but as far as I can tell a lot _fewer_ than 2019. Your problems seem very weird, so maybe it's something with your installation or system.

Answer (score 0):

Since I installed VS 2022 Version 17.1.0 Preview 3.0: I cannot reproduce this problem any more.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had this error in 17.3.3 and think it was caused by not having all the solution's required NuGet package sources added to a new Visual Studio installation.  I solved by going to Tools, Options, NuGet Package Manager, Package Sources and adding all the sources from my previous installation.  Then I restarted Visual Studio, reloaded the solution and the errors were gone.